# Finding the permutations for each data subset

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to find the permutations for each row of a dataframe or each element of an RDD.

either:

```
val df = Seq((1,2,3),(4,5,6)).toDF("A", "B","C")
```

or:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((1,2,3),(4,5,6)))
```

Expected output:

(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3)...

I have tried several flavours of the following but no luck so far

```
df.map(row=>row.toSeq.permutations)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((1,4),(2,5),(3,6)))
rdd.map(x=>x._1.toSeq.permutations)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((1,2,3),(4,5,6)))
rdd.flatMap(_.productIterator.toList.permutations.collect {
  case List(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) => (x, y, z) 
})
```